# How to reorder raw image color data to achieve a specific 2 by 2 format from four images? (C++)

Tags: c++, image-processing

I have the raw color data for four images, let's call them 1, 2, 3, and 4.  I am storing the data in an unsigned char * with allocated memory.  Individually I can manipulate or encode the images but when trying to concatenate or order them into a single image it works but takes more time than I would like.

I would like to create a 2 by 2 of the raw image data to encode as a single image.

```
1 2
3 4
```

For my example each image is 400 by 225 with RGBA (360000 bytes). Iim doing a for loop with memcpy where

```
  for (int j = 0; j < 225; j++)
  {
   std::memcpy(dest + (j * (400 + 400) * 4), src + (j * 400 * 4), 400 * 4); //
  }
```

for each image with an offset for the starting position added in (the example above would only work for the top left of course).

This works but I'm wondering if this is a solved problem with a better solution, either in an algorithm described somewhere or a small library.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

const int width  = 6;
const int height = 4;

constexpr int n  = width * height;

int main()
{
    unsigned char a[n], b[n], c[n], d[n];
    unsigned char dst[n * 4];

    int i = 0, j = 0;

    /* init data */
    for (; i < n; i++) {
        a[i] = 'a';
        b[i] = 'b';
        c[i] = 'c';
        d[i] = 'd';
    }

    /* re-order */
    i = 0;

    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++, i++, j++) {
            dst[i                ] = a[j];
            dst[i         + width] = b[j];
            dst[i + n * 2        ] = c[j];
            dst[i + n * 2 + width] = d[j];
        }

        i += width;
    }

    /* print result */
    i = 0;

    for (int y = 0; y < height * 2; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < width * 2; x++, i++)
            std::cout << dst[i];

        std::cout << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this be much worse?  Without accounting for the rgba you have 90,000 iterations and with the rgba you have 360,000 (one for each pixel in an image).  A lot more copying as well.

Doing whole line copies like I posted would only give 900 iterations.  I guess reducing my exterior loop to do it together like yours would even give 225 iterations with the same number of copy operations though (I would still have to check each to see if a new image for that sector was needed).